# Using xdmp:plan in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, query-tuning

I wanted to compare two queries:

1)

```
xdmp:plan(fn:distinct-values(/ts:top-song/ts:genres/ts:genre/text(), "http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/AS/T00BB"))
```

2)

```
declare variable $options :=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <constraint name="genre">
    <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/AS/T00BB">
      <element ns="http://marklogic.com/MLU/top-songs" name="genre"/>
    </range>
  </constraint>
</options>;

xdmp:plan(search:search("", $options)/search:facet/search:facet-value)
```

I have the following questions:

1. In the result for both the queries I get: Expression is unsearchable. Is this a good thing? Does it mean that indexes are already being used and further indexing cannot be done?
2. (Range index is enabled for genre) I am guessing fn:distict+Xpath uses range indexes but involves filtering due to the Xpath. OTOH search:search uses only value lexicons, so does it do an unfiltered search? 
   If not, is there a way to find the distinct values in an unfiltered fashion?

Answer (score 4):

xdmp:plan does not take an arbitrary expression as its operand: it looks like a function but it really is not. (If you think about it, that must be the case, because if it were a function it would evaluate its arguments first, so it would have no basis for creating the plan.) It is not designed to give you a comparison of two general XQuery expressions, but of the index operations involved in a search or path.

You can only give it either an XPath or a cts:search expression.

So: `xdmp:plan(ts:top-song/ts:genres/ts:genre/text())`

For `search:search` there is an option you use to enable it (`return-plan`)

Comment: can you throw some light on the first question ? What does 'expression is unsearchable' mean exactly ?

Comment: I have used return-plan, which again shows that the query is unsearchable.    Why so ? shouldn't both the approached be exploiting range indexes and value-lexicons ?

Comment: Yes, they should, but you were calling xdmp:plan in an illegal way in both cases. xdmp:plan can't be passed a function call like search:search or distinct-values. When you try to do that you will get that it is unsearchable.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can we say that one of them will be more optimized ?

Comment: to answer Yash.  "Unsearchable'" is a marklogic specific term.  One that many (including myself) too a while to understand.  Its a foundation concept for efficient ML programming so you should spend time researching it.
Roughly:  ML'  implementation of XQuery is 'enhanced' -- not all expressions are equivalent.   Some XQuery expressions are 'special', they are understood natively by the compiler and runtime as 'Searchable'  - i.e. they can be decomposed into index references and query plans.  Not all expressions are 'searchable'. Knowing the difference allows you to understand how to optimize